# NodeJS - Promise Return Values are not received properly

Tags: node.js, es6-promise

**Problem**: I'm supposed to get the proper objects which i'm resolving from promises. But I'm getting empty objects at the very end. SQL Queries which I'm executing are working flawless. Only thing is the proper return value.

**Debugging**: When i try to console the object value before resolving it; is saying "[Promise {}]".

**Output I'm getting**:

```
{
    "status": true,
    "data": [
        {},
        {}
    ],
    "errors": null,
    "msg": "Hahaha"
}
```

Code

```js
export const executeAllQueries = (allQueries) => {
    return allQueries.map ( async productQuery => {
        try {
            let res = await executeProductQuery (productQuery);
            console.log(res); 
            return res;
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            return error;
        }
    })
}

const executeProductQuery = async (productQuery) => {

    let parentResponse = await new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
        mysql.query( productQuery.parent.sql , productQuery.parent.data, (parentError, parentResult) => {
            if (parentError)
                reject ( { status: false, parent_sku: productQuery.parent.data[1], error: parentError.message } )
            else {
                resolve( { status: true,  parent_sku: productQuery.parent.data[1], parent_id: parentResult.insertId , error: null } )
            }
        })
    }); 

    if (parentResponse.status === true)
    {
        let variantPromises = productQuery.varients.map (async varientQuery => {
            try {
                return await executeVariantQuery(varientQuery, parentResponse.parent_id)
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
                return error;
            }
        }); 

        return { parent: parentResponse, varient: variantPromises }
    }
}

const executeVariantQuery = async ( varientQuery, parent_id ) => {

    let varientResponse = await new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
        varientQuery.varient.data[11] = parent_id; 
        mysql.query(varientQuery.varient.sql, varientQuery.varient.data, (varientError, varientResult) => {
            if (varientError)
                reject ( { status: false, error: varientError.message } )
            else {
                resolve( { status: true, varient_id: varientResult.insertId , error: null } )
            }
        })
    })

    if (varientResponse.status === true) {
        let attributePromises = varientQuery.attributes.map(async attribQuery => {
            try {
                return await executeAttributeQuery(attribQuery);
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
                return error; 
            }
        })
        return { varient: varientResponse, attributes: attributePromises }
    }
}

const executeAttributeQuery = async (attribQuery) => {
    let attribResponse = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        mysql.query(attribQuery.sql, attribQuery.data, (attribError, attribResult) => {
            if (attribError)
                reject ( { status: false, error: attribError.message } )
            else {
                resolve( { status: true, varient_id: attribResult.insertId , error: null } )
            }
        })
    })
    return attribResponse; 
}
```

Executing the the top method `executeAllQueries()` as following:

```js
let completeVariants = isolateVariantProducts(fileRows); // All products are isolated in separate groups. Each group has a parent and it's variants.
let allQueries = generateCompleteQueriesForVariant(completeVariants);
let responses = executeAllQueries(allQueries);

res.status(200).json({status: true, data: responses, errors: null, msg: 'Hahaha'})
```

**Runnable NodeJS Snippet:**

```js
let allQueries = [{parent: 1, varients: [1,2,3,4]}, {parent: 2, varient: [5,6,7,8]}]

const executeAllQueries = (allQueries) => {
    return allQueries.map ( async productQuery => {
        try {
            return await executeProductQuery (productQuery);
        } catch (error) {
            return error;
        }
    })
}

const executeProductQuery = async (productQuery) => {

    let parentResponse = await new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
        if (true)
            resolve({ status: true, parent: productQuery.parent, msg: "Resolved"})
        else
            reject({status: false, parent: productQuery.parent, msg: "Rejected"})
    }); 

    if (parentResponse.status === true)
    {
        let variantPromises = productQuery.varients.map (async varientQuery => {
            try {
                return await executeVariantQuery(varientQuery)
            } catch (error) {
                return error;
            }
        }); 

        return { parent: parentResponse, varient: variantPromises }
    }
}

const executeVariantQuery = async ( varientQuery ) => {

    let varientResponse = await new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
        if (true)
            resolve ( { status: true, msg: "Resolved" } )
        else {
            reject ( { status: false, msg: "Rejected" } )
        }
    });
    return varientResponse; 
}

console.log(executeAllQueries(allQueries));
```

Comment: I assume you are not awaiting / using `.then` on a promise. Given the size of your code example, it's a bit hard to determine where. Please try to create a MINIMAL example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @k0pernikus I have added a runnable example at the end. I'm recieving two promise objects, But i should see the resolved objects here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`executeAllQueries` returns array of promises. You should do `Promise.all()` to get results.

```
// Instead of
let responses = executeAllQueries(allQueries);

// do

let responses = await Promise.all(executeAllQueries(allQueries));
```

Comment: this partially solved the problem. As i have other nested promises, I needed to Promise.All nested promises as well. :-)